# mktime function in case of Last day of a month in php

Tags: php, mktime

Understanding of last day of a month in the PHP function `mktime`

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2014));
```

Output is

```
2014-01-31 00:00:00
```

It should be

```
2014-02-28 00:00:00
```

Where is the wrong thing I am doing here?

Comment: day should be `Values 1 to 28, 29, 30 or 31`

Comment: 31 Feb? Seriously? :-)

Comment: @chumkiu its typing mistake, actually I wanted the month should be 2 instead of 1 i.e Feb instead of Feb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem. It looks correct to me.

You have asked for February 0, which is the day before February 1 AKA Jan 31.

Answer (score 2):

if you set day to **0** it will return the last day of month - 1

```
<?php
     $lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2000);
     echo strftime("Last day in Feb 2000 is: %d", $lastday);
     $lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, -31, 2000);
     echo strftime("Last day in Feb 2000 is: %d", $lastday);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 28, 2014)); //You can't show 29 in feb 2014
```

> OUTPUT : 2014-02-28 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Major confusion when you pass the `month` 4th argument and 5th argument as `day = 0` in the mktime method of PHP function.

**From PHP official documentation:**

> Example #3 Last day of a month**
>
> The last day of any given month can be expressed as the "0" day of the next month, not the -1 day. Both of the following examples will produce the string "The last day in Feb 2000 is: 29".

```
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2000);
echo strftime("Last day in Feb 2000 is: %d", $lastday);
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, -31, 2000);
echo strftime("\nLast day in Feb 2000 is: %d", $lastday);
// For Feb 2014
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2014);
echo strftime("\nLast day in Feb 2014 is: %d", $lastday);

$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, -31, 2014);
echo strftime("\nLast day in Feb 2014 is: %d", $lastday);
?>
```

Output as below:

```
Last day in Feb 2000 is: 29
Last day in Feb 2000 is: 29
Last day in Feb 2014 is: 28
Last day in Feb 2014 is: 28
```